# Polerio Gambit game for review

Tags: opening, analysis, kings-gambit

Please analyze and comment about this game  I played as an anonymous uer. I played the **Polerio Gambit** in the game. I would also like remarks about the Polerio Gambit (1. e4 e5 2. f4 exf4 3. d4) as well.

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Lichess.org"]
[Date "2020.03.27"]
[White "BramStokers"]
[Black "Anonymous User"]
[ECO "C33"]
[WhiteElo "1000"]
[BlackElo "1000"]
[TimeControl "10 minutes Blitz type game"]
[Termination "game_result.won_by_resignation"]
[Result "0-1"]

1.e4 e5 2.f4 exf4 3.d4 Nf6 4.Qf3 Bb4 5.c3 Ba5 6.Bxf4 O-O  7.Nh3 Re8 8.e5 d6 9.Bb5 c6 10.Bc4 dxe5 11.Bxf7+ Kxf7 12.Ng5+ Kg8 13.Bxe5 Nfd7 14.Qf7+ Kh8
```

Comment: Wrongly mentioned ```PGN``` notation for the 9th move. It is Bishop's move,- ```9.Bb5 *```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is not really a Polerio, aka [Muzio Gambit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muzio_Gambit) (this is the only name I have ever heard it called). That is characterized by the move 3.Nf3 g5 4.Bc4 g4 5.0-0. You left out some of the opening moves, and the way you played it was lost right out of the opening.

My first impression is that I see a lot of tactical mistakes. There is a beautiful tactic that was missed on move 13. Here are my notes to the game.

```
 [FEN ""]

 1. e4 e5 2. f4 exf4 3. d4 $4 {This is almost losing already.} (3. Nf3 $1 g5 4. Bc4 g4 5. O-O {This is the Muzio/Polerio.}) 3... Nf6 $2 (3... Qh4+ {This is close to winning already.} 4. Ke2 {This is forced, and if so, white needs to deviate sooner.} (4. g3 $2 fxg3 5. Nf3 g2+ $1 6. Nxh4 gxh1=Q $19)) 4. Qf3 $6 Bb4+ $2 {This allows white to solidify the center with tempo.} (4... Nc6 $1 5. c3 d5 6. e5 Ne4 $17 {And black is better.}) 5. c3 Ba5 $2 {The bishop is really needed for the defense of the king.} (5... Be7 $1 {But white is still much better after e5.}) 6. Bxf4 $2 (6. e5 {This drives the knight back to its home, and it clearly the best since white will be way ahead in development.} Ng8 7. Bxf4 Ne7 8. Bd3 {With a huge advantage.}) 6... O-O 7. Nh3 $4 (7. e5 $1) 7... Re8 $4 (7... Nxe4 $1 {This just wins a pawn, and black went from much worse to at least equal.}) 8. e5 d6 $1 {The white king is now stuck in the middle, so black will be winning material.} 9. Bb5 (9. Nd2) 9... c6 (9... Bg4 10. Qd3 Nbd7 {Finishing development is even better.}) 10. Bc4 dxe5 11. Bxf7+ {This is nothing more than a check. Black can take this with impunity.} Kxf7 12. Ng5+ Kg8 13. Bxe5 Nfd7 $4 {Black is crushing here, but instead walks into mate in two. Almost any move here wins, but this one. That said, black had a beautiful, and unique tactic here that wins another piece.} (13... Qxd4 $1 {Exploiting two pins, this wins the Be5.}) 14. Qf7+ 1-0
```

Comment: 13. ... Re5+ 14. de Bf5 seems to win by force, e.g 15. Qf4 Qe1+ 16. Kf2 Qe2 17. Kg1 Bb6+ or 15.Qe3 Qe1+ 16 Ke2 Ng5+, unless I am missing something obvious.

Comment: @user58697 I think you mean 13. ... Re5+ 14. de Bg4 (not Bf5 due to Qxf5 +-) 15. Qf4 Qd1+ (not Qe1) 16. Kf2 Qe2 17. Kg1 Bb6+ or 15.Qe3 Qe1+ 16 Ke2, but it becomes nonsensical here. In addition, the simpler Qxd4 is just absolutely crushing if you see it.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have a bad case of chess dyslexia. It is 14. ... Bg4, and 15. ... Qd1. Now, the second variation 15. Qe3 Qd1 16. Ke2 allows a simple 16. ... Qh1.

Comment: @user58697 I thought that was what you meant, and it wins, but Qd4 is still easier. It is "only" up a piece, but the king will not survive more than a few more moves, and there are no complications. I am always hesitant to win material when my queen ends up on a1/h1/a8/h8. I did that once a long time ago, and lost. I have always remembered that lesson, not that it is not good some of the time, but I am very careful about it now.

Comment: I am with you. In this case there is some dynamics: there is a pin threat from Bb6, g2 pawn is hanging, Black dominates the light squares, and the White Queen can do nothing from e3. No fun for White at all. That said, 13. ... Qd4 is winning, no question about it.